# Reusing method signiture on method of different class

Tags: python, oop, interface, python-typing

I would like to reuse the `method1` signature of `ClassA` on method1_1 `ClassB` somehow like an interface.
What is a general approach to indicate/enforce that `method1_1` has the same signature as `method1_1`?

```py
class ClassA():
  def method1(self, a:int, b:str, c:list[str]):
    pass

class ClassB():
  class_a: ClassA

  def method1_1(self, a:int, b:str, c:list[str]):
    self.class_a(a,b,c)
```

Comment: define it in a base class that both inherit from

Comment: I cannot do that because one class has a relationship already to the other one through a field. I updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduces an abstract base class and a decorator for the abstract base class:

```
import abc
from typing import List


class AbstractDataProcessor(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def process(self, a: int, b: str, c: List[str]): pass


class DataProcessor(AbstractDataProcessor):
    def process(self, a: int, b: str, c: List[str]):
        print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}")


class DataProcessorDecorator(AbstractDataProcessor):
    processor: AbstractDataProcessor

    def __init__(self, processor: AbstractDataProcessor):
        self.processor = processor

    def process(self, a: int, b: str, c: List[str]):
        self.processor.process(a, b, c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = DataProcessorDecorator(DataProcessor())
    p.process(1, "2", ["1", "2", "3"])
```